# Is there a fixed integer $n$ for which ${\pi}^{n}$ is prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, irrational-numbers

I would like to know the relationship between $\pi$ and prime numbers 
distribution ,then I would like to ask if there is a fixed integer for which ${\pi}^{n}$ can be prime or how do i disproof that is can not be prime for any arbitrary integer  $n $ ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: $\pi^n$ is not even an integer, so it can never be a prime.

Comment: If $n=3$ you got that The integer part of the result is 31, and its prime. But I don't think there is some integer $n$ such that $\pi^n$ is a pure integer number..

Comment: As $\pi$ is transcendental, no natural Power of $\pi $ will ever be a natural number, let alone a prime number.

Comment: @KimPeek If you just want the integer part, then take $n=1$ :)

Comment: @5xum lol you're right.. I just went deep to my favorite $\pi^n$ number xD

Comment: @KimPeek: that's kind of cute.  $\lfloor \pi^4 \rfloor$ = 97 which is also prime while $\lfloor \pi^5 \rfloor$ = 306 which is not.  However I'd be *very* surprised if there will ever be any significant results from this.  (Prove me wrong...)

Comment: How amusing!! I don't know any particular significant result about that.. but as one may say: it's just for the love of math!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\pi$ is transendental which means it is not the root to any polynomial with rational coefficients.  That means $x^n - z = 0$ will never have $\pi$ as a root.  So $\pi^n =z \in \mathbb Z$ will never happen.  So $\pi^n$ is never a prime because it is never an integer.

Comment: Of course... I'm expecting you to take my word for it that $\pi$ is transcendental... if someone wants to point in the right direction for that it'd be of interest to the OP.  There are some relations between $\pi$ and the prime numbers but I'm not really up to looking them up right now.

Comment: (sqrt(2))² =2 is prime however sqrt 2 is not integer

Comment: integer is not creterion

Comment: $\sqrt 2$ is algebraic (which means, it solves a polynomial equation). $\pi$ isn't.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik True, but as fleablood said, the problem is that $\pi^n$ will **never be an integer**. That is not so for $\sqrt 2$, because $\sqrt2^n$ is an integer if $n$ is even.

Comment: $\sqrt(2)$ is algebraic.  It is not trancendental.  $\sqrt(2)$ is a root of $x^2 - 2 = 0$.

Comment: I wasn't implying $x \not \in Z \implies x^2 \not \in Z$.  That's obviously not true.  There are irrational numbers that are called algebraic.  These ones can be roots to polynomials (with integer coefficients).  Then there are numbers that are call transcendental.  They are not roots to polynomials.  $\pi$ is transcendental $\sqrt[n]{k}$ is algebraic.

Comment: @menag  solves a polynomial *with rational coefficients*.  $\pi$, of course, solves $x - \pi = 0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number is a good start.